# jQuery: How can I perform an action after .css has executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, lightbox

So my issue is pretty straight forward, since there is seemingly no callback for after a .css is executed, what options do I have for making performing something after a task is done?

I'm creating a simple lightbox, and I need to wait for the center align to finish...

```
$("#img_lightbox").css("top", top);
```

So when that completes, I then need to fade in the whole thing, but since there is no callback option (to the best of my knowledge) it will occasionally start fading in before the alignment finishes... how can this prevented?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why not remove the center align from lightbox css?

Comment: ...? what? I need it to be centered so I center it after load with jquery (since the sizes change based on what is being opened)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything being chained with your jQuery object will execute *after* the function before it. The easiest way to accomplish what you are asking is with [Plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function () {
    //code to execute
    return this;
}
$("#img_lightbox").css("top", top).myPlugin();
```

You could even write a plugin to execute a custom function, so you do not need to create plugins for every function you might happen to need to run:

```
jQuery.fn.myCallback= function (callback) {
    this.each(function () {
        callback.call($(this));
    });
    return this;
}
$("#img_lightbox").css("top", top).myCallback(function () {
    // some code to run where this = $("#img_lightbox")
});
```

But incase I am *still* misunderstanding, you may be wanting a callback for your fade function: (otherwise please clarify more)

```
$("#img_lightbox").fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).css("top", top)
});
```

Comment: I'm really not understanding how this is relevant. I don't need to wait for the page to load, I need to wait for the .css command to complete (after click event) to fade in an element, not for the DOM to finish loading.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood. I will revise... in my defense... it was kind of unclear, and there were two others that thought you meant the same thing.

Comment: try that, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So, this should work for you: `$("#img_lightbox").css("top", top).fadeIn('slow', callback)`. Also .css should work synchronously which is why no callback can be provided here. There's an older discussion about that here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-no-callback-for-css-addclass

Answer (score 1):

Adding and removing CSS styles are synchronous functions -- there is no callback because the next statement will be executed once the style has been applied. *Rendering* of the updated style is slightly different, since that will happen during the next repaint, but unless you're doing some serious number-crunching in your UI code, the difference would be completely unnoticeable. In any case, it would be applied before the 'fading in' starts to happen.

If you're seeing something wrong with your display, I'd suggest that the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery provides you with a way to tell once the document is "ready" and in the correct state to execute code correctly. Use one of the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

or the shorter,

```
$(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

More information at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I always use the document ready variation because of clarity. (And clarity always triumphs shorter code). But what has CSS to do with DOM?

Comment: Thanks gdoron and PoweRoy, I was beginning to think I was crazy since I got two responses telling me to use this.

Comment: Ahh - I think I (and probably the other answer) misunderstood the question. "after a .css is executed" made me think of css file (as in .css extension) - The other answer (referencing plugins and chaining) looks like it should provide a solution